# Статический метод расширения

Tags: c#

У нас есть статические методы:

```
String someString = "someString";
Console.Writeline(someString);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Можем ли мы через методы расширения добавить статический метод к классу Console?
Например:

```
Console.DoSomething();
```

Comment: А для чего это требуется? Какова цель расширения класса `Console` ?

Comment: Никакой цели. Просто привел пример с консолью.
Мне требуется добавить в класс Cursor статичный метод клика мыши:

    Cursor.Click();

Comment: `static void Click(this Cursor cursor) { }`, при условии что `Cursor` не является статическим классом.

Comment: Если вам нужна такая функциональность, то проголосуйте за неё на [visual studio user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2060313-c-support-static-extension-methods-like-f) и в следующих версиях C# при достаточной поддержке эта функциональность может появиться.

Comment: Это покамест не сделано потому, что вы легко можете написать «соседний» статический класс `CursorEx`, в котором определите нужные методы. С instance-методами такой трюк без статических методов был бы сложнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Методы расширения требуют передавать в них экземпляры классов (те, что передаются  первым параметром и предваряются модификатором `this`, именно к этим экземплярам и применяется "расширение"), тогда как `Console` - статический класс.

Comment: Возможно ли это сделать как-нибудь иначе?

Comment: с таким же синтаксисом нельзя. Можно разве что добавить свой класс -раппер (wrapper), статический или обычный, в него дописать необходимые методы и уже его использовать. Но это не относится к методам расширения (впрочем и методы расширения не более, чем синтаксический сахар, делающий то же самое).